# Can run a build pipeline failed when the code coverage below a certain parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I added a .net test build to run my unit test

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Test Public API Project '
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/DWP.CDA.API.Test.csproj'
    arguments: '--output publish_output --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:Threshold=80 /p:ThresholdStat=total /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\Coverage\ --collect "Code coverage"'
```

How can I get a build pipeline failed when code line coverage below 80%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the [Build Quality Checks task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.BuildQualityChecks). You can fail a build based on a number of different Code Coverage [result options](https://github.com/MicrosoftPremier/VstsExtensions/blob/master/BuildQualityChecks/en-US/CodeCoveragePolicy.md)

Another path is that you could do something custom by getting the code coverage results from the [rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/code%20coverage/get%20build%20code%20coverage?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Comment: Does it means I can not only use .net  test command to get the result?

Comment: Checkout the documentation of the build quality task in the marketplace link. You add the task after the test task.